# I can't get the image to change when clicked. The image only changes one time, but it will not change back

Tags: javascript, dom

I can't get the image to change when clicked.
The image only changes one time, but it will not change back.

Here is what I have:

```
function myChevron() {
  if (document.getElementById("myChev").src == "LuckyLottoPictures/mini_Icons_arrowUp.png") {
    var arrow = "LuckyLottoPictures/mini_Icons_arrowDown.png";
    return arrow;
  } else {
    var arrow = "LuckyLottoPictures/mini_Icons_arrowUp.png";
    return arrow;
  }
}

function chevChange() {
  document.getElementById("myChev").src = myChevron();
}
```

Comment: Your code looks just fine. Can you paste your event bunding code?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
function myChevron() {
  if (document.getElementById("myChev").attributes["src"].value== "LuckyLottoPictures\\mini_Icons_arrowUp.png") 
{
   var arrow = "LuckyLottoPictures\\mini_Icons_arrowDown.png";
  return arrow;
} 
else 
{
   var arrow = "LuckyLottoPictures\\mini_Icons_arrowUp.png";
   return arrow;
}
}

function chevChange() {
   document.getElementById("myChev").setAttribute("src", myChevron());
}
```